# AngularJS : ng-repeat in Directive ng-transclude

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, transclusion

Hi I am new to AngularJS so forgive me if this is a simple problem.
I have a simple directive that looks something like this:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'
    };
});
```

I would ideally like the content that gets inserted into my div with ng-transclude to be generated using ng-repeat. So I have an HTML block like this:

```
<my-directive>
    <div ng-repeat="item in data">{{item.name}}</div>
</my-directive>
```

I know that my data array is populated in my controller properly as I can see the requests in my dev tool and i have logged my data object. However, my page isn't generated correctly, all I end up with is something like the following when I inspect my page content:

```
<my-directive>
    <!-- ngRepeat: item in data -->
</my-directive>
```

Is there something wrong with using ng-repeat inside of ng-transclude? I have searched but can't seem to find the answer. Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is the controller:

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{'name': 'Foobar'}];
}]);
```

Comment: The data is coming from my controller. The custom directive is nested in a div with attribute ng-controller="MyController". I was fetching data using $http but to simplify, my controller now just contains $scope.data = [{'name': 'Foobar'}];

Comment: http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/03/transclusion-and-scopes/

Comment: Please share you controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably some issue of scope visibility between your controller and your directive.

Take a look at [[this jsFiddle].](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/1236/)

```
var myModule = angular.module('ui.directives', []);
myModule.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'
    };
});

myModule.controller('myController', function($scope){
    $scope.data = [
        {name: 'foo'},
        {name: 'bar'}
    ];
});

angular.module('myApp', ['ui.directives']);
```

Comment: You were right, it was definitely a scope visibility issue. This helped tremendously. Thanks!